# SWF to EXE converter

Tags: windows, gratis, media-converter, flash

I'm looking for an SWF to EXE converter, because I often need to send SWF files (for example, interactive animations made by myself) to my colleagues, and it if often not easy to explain them, how to open such files (publishing them somewhere in the web isn't an option for now)

I would like to find some free offline soluction for Windows, but I also may use an online service. For now, I tried [SwfTools](http://swftools.sourceforge.net/swf-to-exe.html), but it seems that this software puts some malware into all files, produced with it (checked files via VirusTotal).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Adobe Windows Flash Player Projector](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html):

- free
- Windows
- create .exe from SWF through  "File -> Create projector":

[image]

[image]

Note that for some versions of Windows Flash Player the option "File -> Create projector" might be greyed out, in which case you can try with [older versions of Adobe Flash Player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html) (e.g. [flashplayer10_2r152_32_win_sa.exe](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_10.2.152.32_archive.zip) works for me).

[image]

FYI: [File -> Create projector" is greyed out in Adobe Windows Flash Player Projector 14](https://superuser.com/q/791964/116475).

Comment: In Adobe Flash Player installed on my PC this command is actually greyed out. I followed the link to archived older versions, but I don't understand clearly the process of installation and use: will I need to switch between older and newer version somehow, or will the last installed version just replace previous?

Comment: Comment by BLK_SOFT: *Nope. You don't need to replace the newer one. Inside of zip files, there's lot of exe. Choose flashplayer10_2r152_32_win_sa.exe instead. That's the projector.*